# 144p not available on firefox but available on google chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, flash, plugins

after an update of xubuntu14.04
144p not available on firefox but available on google chrome for any of my videos  in youtube

i have think there are problem with my flash player or simply youtube has some issues with firefox

i have the following packagers installed as adobe plugins [image]

Comment: Youtube supports HTML5. Flash should be abandoned. Go to http://youtube.com/html5 and activate html5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/html5

simply clicked use default player

click the button on the page